# Ubuntu 14.04 - Problems using google chrome logged in

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, browser

I am a Ubuntu 14.04 user (*3.13.0-137-generic #186-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux*) and also a user of Google Chrome (stable version - 64 bits).
I am used to use the browser with my profile signed in, thus, all my data is synchronized with other devices.

I have recently updated the browser version and suddenly it started to crash with the following problem:

When I close the browser, I cannot open it anymore (it doesn't show any screen).
I start by clicking on the chrome icon and I see various processes starting (i see it on htop), and all of them consumes about 0.9% of CPU, but the browser screen does not show.

---

I have the same config in another computer (ubuntu 14.04 with the same chrome version) and it works normally. (with the same account and with a different account too)

---

Researching a little in some forums, I found a suggestion about deleting the directory `~/.config/google-chrome/`.

When I delete this directory, the browser shows up normally.

But there is a detail: if I use it without signing in, it works like a charm (I can close it and open again, everything goes smoothly, the screen shows every time).
But if I sign in using some account, the problem happens (I have tried with more than one: I started by trying using the same account in both computers; then, I tried with a different account in the computer with problems, and the problem was the same). If I close it, I cannot open the browser window anymore, unless I delete the folder `~/.config/google-chrome/` (and thus, all my loaded data is deleted too, all my synced data, and this way I have to login again and wait for the synchronization process to complete).

EDIT from comment: The problem occurs with any user logged in (not only my current one)

EDIT: The version of the chrome browser I am using is 63.0.3239.108 (Official Version) in both computers (the one it works and the one it doesn't).

Comment: How exactly are you using chrome without logging in? Do you mean signing into chrome?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant. When I am not signed in, it works nicely (I can close the browser and reopen it after), but when I am signed in, if I close it, I cannot reopen the browser...

Comment: Please [edit] the following  information into your post. What version of chrome are you using under 14.04 that works on the other computer? What version of chrome are you using on the system that doesn't work as expected? this can be obtained by opening chrome and putting chrome://settings/help in the address bar. Also [edit] in some clarity regarding "any user logged in". Are you taking about different accounts on the system or different google accounts?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to dump the history that Google has for your account as described [here.](https://chrome.google.com/sync) At the bottom of the page you'll see [image: sync]

Click the reset sync button and Sign back into chrome on the affected system.

Comment: I have tried the solution you suggested, but it didn't work either.
The problem occurs with any user logged in (not only my current one).

Comment: If your post doesn't clearly reflect your question you are extremely unlikely to obtain an answer that you like. Please [edit] your post as [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986301/ubuntu-14-04-problems-using-google-chrome-logged-in/988134?noredirect=1#comment1596782_988134) is NOT equal to " I  have the same config in another computer (ubuntu 14.04 with latest stable chrome) and it works normally, I use the same account to login in both." Thank you for helping us help you.